# Creating/editing an object using JTextField

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, arraylist, jtextfield

I'm trying to write a store inventory program, where the program reads in a file of the current inventory which is an ArrayList where the product class just defines each product with the name, price etc. I'm struggling to find a way for the user to enter information for a new object in Product in a JTextField and save all the info after it is all entered and create the object and put it into the ArrayList. Currently my ActionListener class works but when i enter info in a text box and press enter it just pops up a message telling me what i entered. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Make a list
- Make a TextField
- Make Button
- Add Listener to button
- Get the text from the text field or text area
- Add to array list object
- Done :)

Here is all the work you need to do:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayObject= new ArrayList<String>();
JButton button = new JButton();
JtextField textBox = new JtextField ();

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //inside your action listener:
        String add_item_to_array = textBox.getText().trim();
        arrayObject.add(add_item_to_array);             
    }
});
```

Comment: please add some explanation to your answer

Comment: I have added the info requested :) please bump, as this answer is more direct than the one above. Thanks @Philip

Answer (score 1):

Something in your ActionListener like this should work

```
String description = descriptionTextBox.getText();
String price = priceTextBox.getText();

Product p = new Product(description, price);


ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

products.add(p);
```

Comment: Glad I could be of help!